# Facing issue in converting from gulp version 3 to gulp version 4

Tags: gulp

In **gulp version 3**, my `help` gulp task defined as:

```
gulp.task('help', function() {
 var command = chalk.bold.green;
 console.log(command('gulp build-task') + ': runs certain build tasks');
});

gulp.task('default', ['help']);
```

I do the following to convert this to **gulp version 4**:

```
gulp.task('help', function() {
 var command = chalk.bold.green;
 console.log(command('gulp build-task') + ': runs certain build tasks');
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('help'));
```

On running `gulp`, I see the following **error**:

```
[01:58:01] The following tasks did not complete: default, help
[01:58:01] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Also, I want the the `help` task to run first and then `default`. In my version 4 example, `default` runs first.

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to [signal task completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion). Easiest one - your function should return [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)):

```
gulp.task('help', async function() {
   var command = chalk.bold.green;
   console.log(command('gulp build-task') + ': runs certain build tasks');
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('help'));
```

After little clean up:

```
async function help() {
    const command = chalk.bold.green;
    console.log(command('gulp build-task') + ': runs certain build tasks');
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(help));
```